# SharePoint : "The remote server returned an error (401) Unauthorised" error

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, unauthorized

Getting "**The remote server returned an error (401) Unauthorised**" while trying to access it by the C# code by ClientId and ClientSecret.

Please check the below code -

```
string siteUrl = "https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/xxxxx-sharepoint-xxxxx";
string clientID = "********-****-****-****-**********a**";
string clientSecret = "*******************************************=";
using (ClientContext cc = new AuthenticationManager().GetACSAppOnlyContext(siteUrl, clientID, clientSecret))
{
   cc.Load(cc.Web, p => p.Title);
   cc.ExecuteQuery();
   Console.WriteLine(cc.Web.Title);
}
```

How can "The remote server returned an error (401) Unauthorised" error be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `scope` you set does not match the API you are calling. Try changing the `scope` to:

```
string scope = "https://******.sharepoint.com/.default";
```